# SharePoint 2010 - Add WebPart to a Web with PowerShell

Tags: web-part, powershell, spweb

I want to add a webpart to a great number of existing pages.
Is there any PowerShell command to add a webpart to a webpart page?

Comment: When you say "add a webpart to a SPWeb" do you mean you actually want to put the web part on a page within the SPWeb?  Or you just want it to show up in the web part gallery for that SPWeb or ?

Comment: Thanks for your commet! It mean that I want to put a existing WebPart from the WebPart gallery on a site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no PowerShell Command, but you can use the `AddWebPart` method of the [`SPWebPartManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.spwebpartmanager_members.aspx) class to add the WebPart to a WebPartPage:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms157507(v=VS.90)

You can get a `SPWebPartManager` object by calling `WebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager` and providing it your `WebPartPage`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpartmanager.getcurrentwebpartmanager(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Theres nothing like this OOB, but you have pretty much the same options in PowerShell as in say a console application in C#.
So theres the option of coding your own cmdlet that does this for you.
On NBSP i found [this](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2007Dev/Pages/How%20to%20create%20Web%20Part%20instances%20on%20pages%20using%20PowerShell%20and%20SPLimitedWebPartManager.aspx) script that should get you going.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some sample powershell scripts for adding webparts to sites:

A nice, simple, clean code for adding a CEWP:

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2007Dev/Pages/How%20to%20create%20Web%20Part%20instances%20on%20pages%20using%20PowerShell%20and%20SPLimitedWebPartManager.aspx

This one adds a customized web-part:

http://www.sharemuch.com/2010/11/17/using-powershell-to-add-and-configure-sharepoint-2010-webparts/

And this adds a page-viewer webpart - Mr. Hahner made this blogpost especially for me!
http://spcrew.com/blogs/lists/posts/post.aspx?id=21

Comment: Whoops - I just realized that Anders Rask already mentioned one of my links...

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a simple script to add a webpart to a page using PowerShell](http://soreddymanjunath.blogspot.in/2014/07/add-webpart-to-page-using-powershell.html) which is tested and working fine.

Please note that to add a webpart to a page export webpart to your local drive .webpart/.dwp file will be in xml format.

```
cls

asnp "*sh*"

$web=Get-SPweb -Identity "http://SP2013dev.com/sites/addwebpart/"

[xml]$webpartxml= Get-Content -Path "C:\Manju\WPRequest.xml"

$SR = New-Object System.IO.StringReader($webpartxml.OuterXml)

$XTR = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextReader($SR)

$err=$null

$WebPartZoneID = "Topzone"

$WebPartZoneIndex = 0

 try
   {

  $page=$web.GetFile("Pages/default.aspx");

  $bool=$page.CheckedOutBy

       if($bool)
        {
            Write-Host "Page is already Checkout to " $page.CheckedOutBy.UserLogin

            $page.UndoCheckOut()

            Write-Host "Page is Over ridded by " $web.CurrentUser.DisplayName + " to Add Webpart"
        }

    $page.CheckOut();

    $wmgr=$web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($page,    [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared);

    $webpart=$wmgr.ImportWebPart($XTR,[ref]$err);

    $wmgr.AddWebPart($webpart,$WebPartZoneID,$WebPartZoneIndex);

    $page.CheckIn('dude');

    $page.Publish('Adding request Site Webpart') 

    "Request Site WebPart SucessfullAdded" + (Get-Date -DisplayHint Date) | Out-File -Append "C:\OutPutLog.txt" 

     $SR.Close();
    $XTR.Close();
     $web.Dispose()

    }
    catch
     {
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message 

        "Request Site WebPart Failure" + $ErrorMessage  +  (Get-Date -DisplayHint Date) | Out-File -Append "C:\ErrorLog.txt"
    }
```